# RuntimeError: dictionary changed size

Tags: python

I have two nested dictionaries. Each dictionary has a key/value pair that are the same. I have some code that says hey if these are the same, update an existing dictionary with another key/value combo that exists in one of the dictionaries to the other dictionary. I get the error RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration.  I've seen that you can use deepcopy to solve for this, but does anybody else have any other ideas?

```
performances = [
    {'campaign_id': 'bob'},
    {'campaign_id': 'alice'},
]

campaign_will_spend = [
    {'id': 'bob'},
    {'id': 'alice'},
]

for item in campaign_will_spend:
    ad_dictt = dict()
    for willspendkey, willspendvalue in item.items():
        if willspendkey == "id":
            for i in performances:
                for key, value in i.items():
                    if key == 'campaign_id' and value == willspendvalue:
                        i['lifetime_budget'] = item
```

Comment: Going to edit your question so it's possible to actually run it.  :)

Comment: Please provide the entire error message, as well as a [mcve]. _I've seen that you can use deepcopy to solve for this, but does anybody else have any other ideas?_ Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You're causing yourself a lot of trouble by treating dictionaries like lists and iterating over them in their entirety to find a particular item.  Most of the code goes away when you just stop doing that, and the rest of it goes away if you build a dictionary to be able to easily look up entries in `campaign_will_spend`:

```
# Easy lookup for campaign_will_spend dictionaries by id.
cws_by_id = {d['id']: d for d in campaign_will_spend}

for p in performances:
    p["lifetime_budget"] = cws_by_id[p["campaign_id"]]
```

Comment: Sam, you legend, this was perfect and reduced the execution from 18 seconds to 3 seconds.! Thanks so much :)